# C++ How do I read a user's ENTER key input as one of the test conditions in a do-while loop?

Tags: c++

I have one problem that I have tried to solve on my own to the best of my abilities and have gone over countless threads regarding the problem I struggle to solve.

In my main.cpp program, I am required to create a restaurant bill with data provided by the user. I am close to finishing it but the last section of my program I am required to prompt the user for a separator character (e.g. Tab button, Spacebar, comma, & the Enter key) and format the bill by the user's input. Note that I am a beginner and have not reached structures or arrays or classes just to name a few. I am required to use a do-while loop to validate the user's input.

Here is a link to my file.

https://repl.it/@Bemmy1989/Assignment-2

```
do 
{ 
  std::cout << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Enter a seperator: [TAB] button,";
  std::cout << " a comma (,), [SPACEBAR] button," << std::endl;
  std::cout << "or type '\\n' for a new line & press [Enter]: ";
  std::getline (std::cin,seperator);
  if (seperator != "\t" && seperator != "," && seperator != " " && seperator != "\\n")
  {
    std::cout << "Invalid entry. You must choose from the seperaotrs listed above." << std::endl;
   }
} while (seperator != "\t" && seperator != "," && seperator != " " && seperator != "\\n");
```

As you can see, I was able to get the codes for the tab button, spacebar button, and comma. However, I could not the Enter key button code so I had to resort to telling the user to type in \n instead of just having the user press Enter.

Any guidance would be really appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If the `string` is empty when it comes back from `getline`, all that was pressed was enter, so...

```
if (seperator != "\t" && seperator != "," && seperator != " " && seperator != "")
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much! I would have not thought of this simple solution on my own.